# Build Error “Type …. is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule - Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to create my APK for android and I run the following command:

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --release
```

Ionic version: **Ionic V3**

My application is not doing lazy loading (I don't even know how to do that hahah) and I have used the ionic cli to create every page.

When I run the command above I following error:

> Error: Type AutomaticPage in
>   C:/Users/tamo/Desktop/dpHydmech/Hydmech/src/pages/automatic/automatic.ts
>   is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in
>   C:/Users/tamo/Desktop/dpHydmech/Hydmech/src/app/app.module.ts and
>   AutomaticPageModule in
>   C:/Users/tamo/Desktop/dpHydmech/Hydmech/src/pages/automatic/automatic.module.ts!
>
> Please consider moving AutomaticPage in
>   C:/Users/tamo/Desktop/dpHydmech/Hydmech/src/pages/automatic/automatic.ts
>   to a higher module that imports AppModule in
>   C:/Users/tamo/Desktop/dpHydmech/Hydmech/src/app/app.module.ts
>
> and AutomaticPageModule in
>   C:/Users/tamo/Desktop/dpHydmech/Hydmech/src/pages/automatic/automatic.module.ts.
>   You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes
>   AutomaticPage in
>   C:/Users/tamo/Desktop/dpHydmech/Hydmech/src/pages/automatic/automatic.ts
>
> then import that NgModule in AppModule in
>   C:/Users/tamo/Desktop/dpHydmech/Hydmech/src/app/app.module.ts and
>   AutomaticPageModule in
>   C:/Users/tamo/Desktop/dpHydmech/Hydmech/src/pages/automatic/automatic.module.ts.

**Things I have tried:**

1. Removing file automatic.module.ts
2. Remove imports everything from automatic.module.ts
3. Remove the AutomaticPageModule import from app.module.ts

I took a look to this:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/build-error-type-is-part-of-the-declarations-of-2-modules-appmodule/129767

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/uncaught-error-type-homemainpage-is-part-of-the-declarations-of-2-modules-please-consider-moving-homemainpage-to-a-higher-module-that-imports-ionicmodule-and-appmodule/105456/10

**Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is because you added automatic.ts in two modules.
So if you remove one it will be working well

Comment: Yeah I tried removing it from the automatic.module.ts and app.module.ts and no luck :(

Comment: Can you share your automatic and app module?

Comment: That worked. The reason why it didn't work for me before was because I was editing the wrong ionic project lololol